# How to delete attributes in an xml file by using a linux command (example sed)

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix

I have the following xml file. I want to edit it by removing the `url` and `title` attributes from every element `<doc></doc>`.  I am looking for a unix command that can help instead of writing a whole code.

---

```
<documents>
<doc id="852" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=852" title="...">
<text>
 Some text...
</text>
</doc>

<doc id="853" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=853" title="...">
<text>
 Some text...
</text>
</doc>

<doc id="854" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=854" title="...">
<text>
 some text...
</text>
</doc>

</documents>
```

Comment: I'm thinking `sed` could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the xML is as consistent as this, a simple example that could work is:

```
sed -r 's/^(<doc .* )url=".*/\1>/' myfile.xml
```

That says to identify lines that start with a `<doc` tag, save the contents up to `url`, discarding the rest of the line, and re-closing with a new `>`.

You could get more careful with the regex, but sed is a good tool for this, *IF* the XML is totally predictable.

If you want to change the file in-place, add a `-i` to the sed invocation.